# Cannot find my database when trying to import with mysql

Tags: mysql, shell, database-administration

When I connect to the mysql shell and do a `SHOW DATABASES`, i get this

```
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| rd7                |
| rural              |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Yet when i try to connect in the shell terminal like this

```
mysql -u user -puser  --host=localhost rd7 <rurdevdrpl.sql
```

I get `"unknown database rd"`.

Comment: Check the contents of the SQL file "rurdevdrpl.sql" - that probably contains (absolute) references to the database name "rd"

Comment: Are you logged in as a user that can see that `rd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have a reference to a database `'rb'` in the sql file `rurdevdrpl.sql`.
It could either be that `rb` has been defined as the default database with

```
USE rb;
```

or as an option to a sql statement like e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE rb.test (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 4);
```

So check your file for occurences of these two. To replace them you could use `sed`, but it's difficult to provide a working command without knowing the format used in the sql files, e.g. if backticks are used for object references etc.